# Show with car going over cliff into the (actual) Grand Canyon

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show

I was at the Grand Canyon last week and did a tour of the west rim. During the tour, one of the guides pointed to the bottom of the cliff and there was (what appears to be) a mangled up car that is all rusted. The tour guide said that the car was pushed over the cliff for a scene in a (1960s?) movie. He didn't say which one though and I don't believe it was for [Thelma & Louise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thelma_%26_Louise), as the car going over the cliff (which is supposed to be at the Grand Canyon) at the end is actually in [Dead Horse Point State Park, Utah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Horse_Point_State_Park). I'm also not 100% sure that this is from a movie or a TV show. I have posted a picture of the car at the bottom of the canyon below (it is the thing in the bottom middle of the picture). Does anyone have any idea?

[image: Car at the bottom of cliff]

Here's a closeup of the car (if it helps):

[image: Car wreckage enlargement]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this site](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2013/06/130622-grand-canyon-stunts-wallenda/), Dar Robinson jumped a car off a ramp from a section of the canyon belonging to the Hualapai Indian Reservation (which is on the west rim) in 1980 for a reality television show called *That's Incredible!*.  Apparently he couldn't get a permit for the stunt from the Grand Canyon National Park.  The car wound up at the bottom of the canyon.

Comment: I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dz0YxCHufx0) (in German) that shows Dar Robinson doing the stunt. The first bit is about him jumping off the CN Tower and then a bit on jumping over a bunch of cars, but if you fast forward to [4:29](http://youtu.be/Dz0YxCHufx0?t=4m29s) you'll see him do the jump. It also looks like he jumped from the opposite side of where my photo was taken. Thanks!

Comment: Chuck Norris narrates this one  (which makes it more bad-ass) and the jump is at the very beginning.  Haven't watched it all, but I'm assuming it's covered again somewhere later in the program.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQU7-jmikmA

Comment: Is it terrible of me to want to see the crash in the video? Yes, happy days Dar Robinson popped his chute, *but I wanna see the crash!* :D